# Partially Upload Listview data using UpdatePanel in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I want to partially update data of this listview.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_SoldItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView_SoldItems_ItemDataBound"  >

            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:SongUC runat="server" id="SongUC" />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

If it wasn't a listview I could have done this.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />  
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:ListView ID="ListView_SoldItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView_SoldItems_ItemDataBound"  >

            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:SongUC runat="server" id="SongUC" />
            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:ListView>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So what would be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_SoldItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView_SoldItems_ItemDataBound" ClientIDMode="AutoID" >
```

Just had to add the **ClientIDMode="AutoID"** property to the Listview.